# Strange print syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have a parenthesis and quations around my print statement, it looks the same as my other print statements, but I am getting a syntax error. What is wrong? (it's the final print statement in this block of code)

```
def printSummary(itemRecords) :
    # printSummary prints a summary from the itemRecords dictionary
    print("ID     NAME     Start Available     Reservations     Subtractions     End Stock")
    print("---     -----   --------------       ----------       -----------      ---------")
    for rec in itemRecords.values():
        print("{0:5s} {1:12s} {2:6d} {3:6d} {4:6d} {5:6d}".format(rec.getID(), rec.getName(), rec.getAvailableStart(), rec.getReservations(), rec.getCancellations(), rec.getAvailableEnd())
    #print the footer
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: Check the line before the last print.

Comment: BTW, use tabulate package. It'll be neater.

Comment: To follow up on the slightly cryptic comment from @tkausl, I'll also rather cryptically suggest you check your code editor to see if it has a matching bracket highlighting function.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace in your penultimate print.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution to your problem:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

def printSummary(itemRecords) :
    result = list()
    headers = ["ID", "NAME", "Start Available", "Reservations", "Subtractions", "End Stock"]
    result.append(headers)

    for rec in itemRecords.values():
        row_rec = list()
        row_rec.append([rec.getID(), rec.getName(), rec.getAvailableStart(), rec.getReservations(), rec.getCancellations(), rec.getAvailableEnd()])
        result.append(row_rec)


    print tabulate(result, headers="firstrow")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this line: you are missing parameter.

Wrong:

```
print("{0:5s} {1:12s} {2:6d} {3:6d} {4:6d} {5:6d}".format(rec.getID(), rec.getName(), rec.getAvailableStart(), rec.getReservations(), rec.getCancellations(), rec.getAvailableEnd())
```

Right:

```
print("{0:5s} {1:12s} {2:6d} {3:6d} {4:6d} {5:6d}".format(rec.getID(), rec.getName(), rec.getAvailableStart(), rec.getReservations(), rec.getCancellations(), rec.getAvailableEnd()))
```